# javascript: get the normalized from two slightly different strings

Tags: javascript

I have two strings of equal number of slashes and the same letter in each position. There is always one letter and a square bracket indicating an index. There will always be a corresponding letter in both strings.

```
var first = "/a/b[1]/c/d[3]/e[1]/f"
var second = "/a/b[1]/c/d[4]/e/f"
```

I expect output should be

```
result = "/a/b[1]/c/d/e/f"
```

This is what I came up with but maybe there's a better way of doing it as it returns `/a/b/c/d/e/f` which is not what i wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/3PM9H/

```
   var first = "/a/b[1]/c/d[3]/e[1]/f".split("/");
var second = "/a/b[1]/c/d[4]/e/f".split("/");

for (var i=0; i < first.length; i++){
firstMatch = first[i].match(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g);
secondMatch = second[i].match(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g);

if (firstMatch != secondMatch){
   first[i] = first[i].replace(/\[([0-9]+)\]/g,'') //get rid of the square bracket.
}
}

first.join("/");
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this [here](https://github.com/djechlin/levenshtein-transformation). It's a node project but the main file is dependency-less hence portable.

Use the dynamic programming algorithm to compute the Levenshtein distance, and use that transform to generate the regex. Subsitutes become wildcards, inserts or deletes become optional characters.

```
var Levenshtein = require('levenshtein-transformation)';
var lev = new Levenshtein(str1, str2);
console.log(lev.regex());
```

Comment: i dont have node, can i use this in browser?

Comment: @user299709 You can probably use browserify or whatever. But the main file Levenshtein.js is dependency-less as I just said. You can copy and paste it and it'll work.

Comment: I can't use this seems like it requires additional node modules in the .js script `var regexpQuote = require('regexp-quote');
var assert = require('assert');` This would be great if there was a browser version.